# iOS Extension Icon

Tags: ios, xcode, actionsheet

I am totally stuck on a small annoying issue in Xcode 12.4
Made a very simple iOS app for the iPad that uses an "Action Extension" (add an action to the action sheet when you tap 'Share' in any iOS app).

It all works perfect, except, I cannot manage to set the icon on the action sheet.. It defaults to an inverted empty app icon (black). See attached picture.

Unable to find any information on how to set this icon properly.
Any one a solution for this?

Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.2 in Objective C

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So many Google's later found that you need to add the appIcon in the "Build Settings" for that Target. By default it's empty..

Comment: can you add some more detail on where you set this in the Build Settings?